# DataAnnotations Required Attribute Copying to Other Classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have 2 classes with some similar fields. In 1 class, some of these fields are required, while they aren't required in the other field.

```
public class Hyun
{
    [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [MaxLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Customer Name must be under 300 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Meanwhile, I also have (without the Required attribute):

```
public class Chan
{
    [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
    [MaxLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Customer Name must be under 300 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using the built in ASP.NET MVC Create template for Chan, puts the required message on the Name field which it copied from Name in Hyun. Commenting that line in Hyun class removes it from the Chan Create page. Why is the attribute copying over to the other class?

Note, there are other classes than just these 2 and the required attribute is copying from any other class with the required attribute on the Name field.

Here is the relevant part of the form:

```
@model Proj.Models.Chan

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What you're describing is impossible. There's something logical causing thi; you simply haven't found it yet. In particular, be careful of inheritance, as you may have a base class that is requiring the property. There, the `new` keyword is your friend, to hide the base class property.

Comment: It seemed like something impossible to me too; that's why I was shocked. Also, neither of these classes inherits from the other. It's especially shocking that the Chan class got the Required attribute from 3 different classes, which each have nothing to do with each other.